# Get multiple values for same parameter name in request URL - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application a request comes from the client with the following URL.`localhost:8080/api/invoice?invoiceNo=1234&invoiceDate=050218&invoiceNo=6543&invoiceDate=060218`

How can I get the values for the request property invoiceNo and invoiceDate. I know we can always use some delimiter while building the URL and fetch it. 
I would like to know if there is any springboot way for achieving this.
Any help is much appreciated.
Now when I try `request.getParameter("invoiceNo")` I get only the first parameter.

Comment: There are two of each, do you need both, or there is some override logic?

Comment: Try `request.getParameterValues('invoiceNo');`

Comment: @khachik yes I need both the values.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Thanks that worked !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use List

```
public void invoice(@RequestParam(name="invoiceNo") List<String> invoiceNos, @RequestParam(name="invoiceDate") List<String> invoiceDates) {
```

Comment: Thanks I just posted that answer

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. It can also be Set.

Answer (score 2):

In spring you can get query parameters by using the annotation `@RequestParam` inside controller's endpoint method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/invoice")
public CustomResponse getInvoiceData(
        @RequestParam(value="invoiceNo") List<Long> invoiceNoList,
        @RequestParam(value="invoiceDate", required = false) List<Date> invoiceDateList){
    ...
}
```

You can see another values that this annotation can get (like required, default, etc..) in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @maruthi mentioned `request.getParameterValues("invoiceNumber")` is one way. Another way is to add `@RequestParam(value="invoiceNo", required=false) List<String> invoiceNo` as the controller method parameter.

Comment: if request url looks like this : localhost:8080/api/invoice?invoiceNo=1234,1235                        
 i want to pass mutltiple values in single queryparam ? how to pass multiple values